# Casting a pointer to a struct into another struct type with a smaller number of fields

Tags: c++, pointers, reflection, struct, reinterpret-cast

**Basic problem**

I'm in a tricky situation that requires taking a pointer to a struct `mainset` and turning this into a pointer to a struct `subset`, whose fields are a contiguous subset of the fields of `mainset`, starting from the first. Is such a thing possible, with well-defined behavior? I realize that this is a pretty terrible thing to do, but I have good and frustrating reasons to do it [explained at the bottom for patient readers].

My attempt an an implementation *seems* to work, on OS X with the clang compiler:

```
#include <iostream>

struct mainset {
    size_t size;
    uint32_t reflex_size;
};

struct subset {
    size_t size;
};

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    mainset test = {1, 1};
    subset* stest = reinterpret_cast<subset*>(&test);
    std::cout << stest->size << std::endl;
}
```

The output is indeed 1, as I expect. However, I wonder: am I just getting lucky with a particular compiler and a simple case (in reality my structs are more complicated), or will this work in general?

Also, a follow-up question: for other annoying reasons, I worry that I might need to make my larger struct

```
struct mainset {
    uint32_t reflex_size;
    size_t size;
};
```

instead, with the extra field coming at the front. Could my implementation be extended to work in this case? I tried replacing `&test` with `&test+sizeof(test.reflex_size)` but this didn't work; the output of the `cout` statement was 0.

**Explanation of why I have to do this**

My project uses the GSL library for linear algebra. This library makes use of structs of the form

```
struct gsl_block {
   size_t size;
   double* data;
}
```

and similar structs like `gsl_vector` and `gsl_matrix`. So, I've used these structs as members of my C++ classes; no problem. A recently demanded feature for my project, however, is to enable reflection to my classes with the [Reflex](https://root.cern.ch/how/how-use-reflex) tool, part of the ROOT ecosystem. To enable reflection for a struct like this in Reflex, I must add an annotation like

```
struct gsl_block {
   size_t size;
   double* data; //[size]
}
```

This annotation tells Reflex that that the length of the array is provided by the field `size` of the same struct. Normally that would be that, *but* Reflex and ROOT have a very unfortunate limitation: the length field must be 32 bit. Having been informed that this limitation won't be fixed anytime soon, and not having the time/resources to fix it myself, I'm looking for workarounds. My idea is to somehow embed a struct bit-compatible with `gsl_block` within a larger struct:

```
struct extended_gsl_block {
   size_t size;
   double* data; //[reflex_size]
   uint32_t reflex_size;
}
```

and similar things for `gsl_vector` and `gsl_matrix`; I can ensure that `reflex_size` and `size` are always equal (neither is ever bigger than ~50) and Reflex will be able to parse this header correctly (I hope; if reflex_size is required to precede data as a field something more difficult would be required). Since GSL routines work with pointers to these structs, my idea is this: given a pointer `extended_gsl_block*`, somehow get a pointer to just the fields `size` and `data` and `reinterpret_cast` this into a `gsl_block*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck.

The classes you show as an example conform to the requirements of *standard layout* types.

You can read more here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout

You can test this premise in the compiler with:

```
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<gsl_block>::value, "not a standard layout");
```

Comment: Thanks! Consulting that reference, as best as I can tell all the types I am working with are in standard layout, as all the data types are non-static and non-references (since the structs are all C structs, really). So, hopefully my luck continues. There might be thornier details down the road, especially regarding how memory is allocated for these structs...